# Why would the Nostromo have a self-destruct mechanism?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Just been watching the excellent *Alien* movie and wondered: why would the *Nostromo*, an innocuous civilian cargo vessel, have a multi-million-dollar built-in self-destruct mechanism?

Comment: Because otherwise Ripley could not blow the ship up at the end of the movie to kill the Alien.  Not that it worked, she later had to fry it with the shuttle's engine.

Comment: The destruct mechanism might be extremely cheap. All I see is a plastic sign and a programmatical countdown timer

Comment: It occurs that a self-destruct mechanism might be useful if the crew is unable to think of any other way to prevent the ship from catastrophically impacting an object such as a planet

Comment: Any ship is basicallly equivalent to a dinosaur killer asteroid 
 See for example https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144239/old-sf-story-about-the-need-to-destroy-an-out-of-control-passenger-ship-with-a-n

Comment: Plausible deniability? The company were up to some sneaky stuff.

Comment: *Nostromo* is a commercial freigther in a cut-throat future capitalist universe. It makes sense that in order to deter piracy from rival companies, all freighters have self-destruct mechanisms to let possible pirates know that they have nothing to gain except violent death. Crew expendable, of course.

Comment: While ocean ships don't have a fancy explosive self-destruct, scuttling (deliberately sinking) a ship to keep it from being a hazard, or to keep it out of undesirable hands is certainly well-precedented.  Here on Earth, particularly in centuries past, the ocean itself provides a formidable barrier to recovery of the ship/cargo, even if you know where it's at.  I WOULD GUESS THAT in space, assuming you track/run across an abandoned ship, there's really nothing preventing you from taking whatever of value you want.  So I WOULD GUESS a space-scuttle would, of necessity, be a bit more...complete

Comment: @Valorum Would the impact of the blown-up ship kill a lot less dinosaurs than the intact ship? (I have no idea, all I know about science is from reading sci-fi.)

Comment: @user14111 - Depending on the size of the explosion, some of the debris would hit at a more oblique angle or miss entirely. Also smaller pieces would burn up in the atmosphere more easily, noting that one 'city-killer asteroid' worth of space crap hits the Earth every single day.

Comment: @Valorum Wow, I didn't know that. Still, I guess the incoming cloud of debris from a sci-fi ship travelling at a ridiculous speed might be more dangerous than normal space crap?

Comment: @user14111 - Very much so. If they're moving at FTL speeds, even a tiny object is basically going to impart enough energy to be a catastrophic impact; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwgMjr-Qu1Y

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, during war, cargo transported for war effort is loaded onto civilian ships, mostly. What any navy has in it's inventory, in terms of cargo shipping, is basically for peacetime internal needs or specialized units that are part of naval formations (i.e. ro-ro ships, tankers attached to carrier battle groups etc.)

Those civilian ships would be privately owned and operated for the simple reason that no navy has the resources to take them over and run them; also it usually is counterproductive. For example, merchant cargo vessel has only as many crew members on board as is necessary. Navy usually operates with larger complements compared to civilian crews for redundancy.

*[See: [Everything You’ve Always Wanted to Know about the Merchant Marine But Were Afraid to Ask](https://veteransbreakfastclub.org/everything-youve-always-wanted-to-know-about-the-merchant-marine-but-were-afraid-to-ask/)]*

That being said, merchant vessels are legitimate targets in war if they are operated by the warring state or are required to operate within that state's military structure.

*[See: [Naval Targeting:
Lawful Objects of Attack](https://Naval%20Targeting:%20Lawful%20Objects%20of%20Attack)]*

So, to avoid capturing ships and cargo by the enemy, they can be (though this is captain's decision, of course - civilians are not military) equipped with self-destruct to facilitate that desire to avoid capture.
(the *[Wartime Instructions for United States Merchant Vessels](https://www.history.navy.mil/research/library/online-reading-room/title-list-alphabetically/w/wartime-instructions-united-states-merchant-vessels-1942.html)* does not mention scuttling, just rules for engagement to avoid capture; practical outcome of capturing of a cargo vessel by belligerent was scuttling anyway)

Self-destruct as an installation (because it's not a single device) is rarely encountered as it's quite expensive piece of equipment to acquire and then maintain.
This is because such installation is expected to work when needed and only when needed - accidental activation is rather irreversible, and that includes all kinds of damage, up to and including combat-related. And, of course, it is designed to be initiated from single source.

For the most part such devices are not found on commercial vessels for the simple reason that they are not needed - practically every ship can (and historically could have been; we know this happened from many records) be scuttled, that is: intentionally sunk. This always was - and is - achieved by either blowing holes in the bottom of the vessel by brute force (i.e. men with axes and hammers), opening specially installed for this reason scuttling plugs or by placing explosive devices in vulnerable places. In first and second cases this was very dangerous operation, so would be done by volunteers, in the last scenario explosives would be produced and placed just before the actual scuttling.

[*As mentioned in ["The Grand Scuttle"](https://archive.org/details/grandscuttlesink0000vand_t8c2/page/130/mode/2up), the scuttling crews would prefer to have explosives to open flood valves - due to overgrowth of barnacles on the outer hull and had to remove any controls of those valves on the open decks on the ships. The opening of the valves on the day of scuttling was done by designated crews and hammers, axes and other tools were laid out next to the valves to do the work as expeditiously as possible. Even with all precautions and days of preparation, 8 sailors were killed during scuttling.*]

In terms of Nostromo the self destruct caused a meltdown and subsequently explosion of the power source.*[See [Emergency destruction system Aboard the_Nostromo](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Emergency_destruction_system#Aboard_the_Nostromo)]*

However, in stark contrast to what I wrote earlier, such self-destruct is neither expensive nor necessarily built-in. The multiple positive-action locks in the ESD installed in the ship make it look complicated and/or expensive, but while it is a very nice solution - very hardware-oriented - it just overloads fusion reactor... CM-88B Bison is a nuclear-powered vessel, and as such the self-destruct, as could be in general in spaceships, doesn't have to be something complicated. Doesn't even have to be a part of the ship's operating procedures - in a pinch it can be "jury-rigged", obviously, because any engineer knows how to intentionally destroy any nuclear device he or she is responsible for, given some time and tools...

In general case of the spaceships there is yet another dimension to all of the above - any space-going vessel can be turned into a kinetic projectile. Or - in words of [lucasbachmann](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/72573/lucasbachmann) in one of the comments to the OP- "*Any ship is basically equivalent to a dinosaur killer asteroid*".

Though this last one is the only viable reason a cargo vessel would have one, in my opinion, best explanation would be that W-Y Corp. put it in ALL it's vessels in the case of the situation like the one Nostromo encountered. After all, they kind of knew something...

Comment: This all feels like complete guesswork. Can you offer any evidence to back it up?

Comment: @Valorum - you want me to source the contracts with US Navy for a ship during WWII, for example? Or some construction plans for a ship that has scuttling plugs and an example of use? What next, proving water is wet? I understand what your request is, but when there is a talk about building a house, no one asks for description how to lay bricks and what is formula for cement...

Comment: If I asked what the walls of Ripley's house are made of and you said "They're clearly brick because houses in 1942 are made of bricks", I'd have the same issue

Comment: @Valorum - That's not an argument. What you asked me was rather equivalent of the exchange: Me - here are some buildings; You: how do we know they were built and how? Nevertheless - here, have some sources. Hopefully you'll bother to at least click the links...

Comment: It is obvious why a warship would have this capability. But I think a non-warship is just about as obvious. The Prometheus we were told cost something like one trillion dollars (or the entire mission did, but most of that would be spaceship). If WT thought a competitor was going to steal this valuable item, not to mention the intellectual property of its design, WT would consider perhaps suing but also would be worried about jurisdiction so would also perhaps want to destroy it -- no way let another company have it, at least have leverage of destroying it if the buyer wd not pay the asking.

Comment: If it's obvious, you should be able to provide some obvious in-universe evidence. The reason you're arguing in comments is because you obvious(ly) can't :-)

Comment: @Valorum - oh, you sneaky... :-P

Comment: I think what @Valorum is trying to say is that while this is very logical and well reasoned, "logical & well reasoned" aren't _generally_ acceptable as answers here at SF&F without some sort of in-universe supporting evidence _or_ some sort of statement out-of-universe from a director, writer, etc saying "this is so".

Comment: @FreeMan - Precisely. And for the record, the reason the Nostromo has a self-destruct is because the director stated (in the audio commentary) that he "needed a way to blow up the ship" and to "create tension", noting that the original method of destruction wasn't a self-destruct at all, it was just Ripley mucking with the engines.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not a native English speaker,  so my understanding of the question deviates slightly from yours. Had there be "did" instead of "would", I'd not even argue... So, am I right or am I? I can rewrite this answer no problem, but I do think now it answers the question better.

Comment: My issue is that this answer is a great answer to the question "*why do sailing ships of the 1940s have a self-destruct mechanism?*"

Comment: @Valorum This is quite an old thread, I just wanted to say I think the reasons why historical ships had self-destruct mechanisms and transferring those to "Alien" is quite valid even without in-universe evidence. After all, the Nostromo is a ship built by humans in Earth's future, and it would not be the first time that modern things are using techniques and devices which were invented earlier if they would still be useable for the same purpose. And since out-of-universe it was just to create tension, there is no "real" in-universe reason and the historical explanation is as good as any other.